# How to use Terminus (TTF) font in Microsoft Visual Code Editor

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I'm successfully using [Terminus TTF font](https://files.ax86.net/terminus-ttf/) in Visual Studio. I downloaded: https://files.ax86.net/terminus-ttf/files/latest-windows.zip

[image]

How to use Terminus font in Visual Studio Code? What is the name of the font. I tried:

- Terminus
- Terminus (TTF)
- Terminus TTF

Where can one know the font name to use in editors like Sublime, Studio code, ...
[image]

Comment: How did you get this pixel-perfection? Have you disabled font smoothing on OS-level? Or there's a way to disable it just in VS Code? I'm using Windows 10 and wasn't able to get there without disabling it on OS-level which affects a lot of other apps that can't be configured with proper font and thus look ugly.

Answer (score 5):

All I needed was to escape fontFamily value:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Terminus \\(TTF\\)",
"editor.fontSize": 16,
```

Comment: If using the Windows version of the font, use `"editor.fontFamily": "Terminus \\(TTF\\) for Windows",`

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @broadband and the comment by @FlorianCastellane both didn't work for me using VSCode 1.30 and later.

I have found out that font names can be written within single quotes which in the end enabled Terminus for me.

`"editor.fontFamily" : "'Terminus (TTF) for Windows', Consolas"`

Answer (score 1):

For me (under Linux) as well as installing the TTF version of the font, I also had to adjust the line height as the lines were spaced too far apart:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Terminus (TTF)', 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace",
"editor.fontSize": 16,
"editor.lineHeight": 18,
```

Comment: This worked for me on OSX as well.